# Reasons for limits in triple integral of sphere

Tags: calculus

I know that the volume of a sphere is given by the triple integral $ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^r \rho ^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta $.

I am having trouble on how the limits for the angles are derived. Why don't they both go up to $2\pi$. Please help.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for the question but I am not able to understand and visualize the limits with those answers.

Comment: Just look at a globe.

Comment: @Gaffney Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Latitude only has 180 degrees.

Comment: @Gaffney Can you explain why ?

Comment: Because then you've covered the globe.  Where would you put the extra degrees?

Comment: @Gaffney But, it's a full circle. Why only 180 and not 360 ?

Comment: No, it's *not* a full circle, that's the point! How far from the north pole can you get? Answer: 180 degrees. You reach the south pole after *half* a circle. If you go further, you start going *back* again, and reach points that you already cover by going (less than 180 degrees) from the north pole in another direction.

Comment: @HansLundmark Why doesn't this hold for the equator ?

Comment: The coordinate system is set up in such a way that the north and south poles are special. There are two angles, one which describes how far south you need to go from the north pole in order to reach the target point (and that's between 0 and 180 degrees, since **you can't go further south than the south pole**), and another angle which tells you in which direction to go from the north pole (and that angle has to go from 0 to 360 degrees, or -180 to 180, or however you like to describe a full circle, since **you must be able to describe all directions**).